# azure devops variables from task to templates

Tags: windows, templates, variables, azure-devops, devops

I need to pass the variables into templates. For example, the output of `Small` (found below) should be passed as input to medium. How is this possible?

```
template: windows-tests.yml
parameters:
integration_tests: ["Small", "Medium"]
check_status: "$(Powershell1.var)"
```

In addition to the above, I would like to add
**o/p from build step will be stored in checkstatus variable and will be passed to template.**

`Powershell1.var` will be used by small test and then generated a value which needs to be used by medium.

Comment: Please check if my answer can help you. I don't understand what you mean by "o/p". Does it mean the `powershell1.var`? Please feel free to let me know if there is any misunderstanding.

Comment: I want to set a flag(check_status) throughout the pipeline from build step through unit,integration test(small and medium).This flag is used to setup auto deployment.if any of the steps fails or error out,then this flag will be set to false and deployment should be stopped.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to pass the variables into templates.

You can refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops#passing-parameters) for instructions on how to pass variables in templates.

> the output of `Small` (found below) should be passed as input to `Medium`.

Here is the script:

Template:

```
parameters:
- name: Medium
  type: {data type of `Medium`}
  default: {defualt value of `Medium`}
```

Pipeline:

```
extends:
  template: {template file}
  parameters:
      Medium: $(Small)
```

> I would like to add o/p from build step will be stored in checkstatus variable and will be passed to template.

Here is the script:

Template:

```
parameters:
- name: check_status
  type: string
  default: "$(Powershell1.var)"
```

Pipeline:

```
extends:
  template: {template file}
  parameters:
      check_status: "$(Powershell1.var)"
```

Comment: Pipeline

template: windows-tests.yml
parameters:
    integration_tests: [“Small”, “Medium”]
    check_status: “$(Powershell1.var)”

Comment: code inside template

$error_Code=$?
if (“$error_Code” -eq “True” -and “$(Powershell2.check_status)” -eq “true”)
{
Write-Host “##vso[task.setvariable variable=check_status;isOutput=true]true”
}
else { Write-Host “##vso[task.setvariable variable=check_status;isOutput=true]false”
}

Comment: I am able to set check_status value based on input provide.I want to use the flag set in small as a input to Medium.This i am unable to do it

Comment: @ Jane Ma-MSFT Could you please help me with solution?

Comment: @Sindhu So what you want is the output of `small` should be passed as input to `medium`? Have you tried the first and second paragraphs of scripts provided in my answer? Do they meet your requirements?

Comment: I want to pass both small and medium parameters in the same template

Comment: @  Jane Ma-MSFT, I am unable to move the o/p of small as input to medium

Comment: azure-pipelines.yml 
 - template: windows-integration-tests.yml
    parameters:
      integration_tests: ["SmallTest", "MediumTest"]
      check_status: "$(Powershell2.check_status)"--->o/p of small should be passed here 

inside template windows-integration-tests.yml
parameters:
  integration_tests: []
  check_status: []

Comment: if ("$error_Code" -eq "True" -and  "$(Powershell2.check_status)" -eq "true")
          {
            Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=check_status;isOutput=true]false"
          }
          else
          {
             Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=check_status;isOutput=true]true"
          }